# Parse iOS SDK: Select columns from compound query

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse iOS SDK to pull data from my Parse backend. What I would like todo is create a compound query, so a query with a subquery as a where condition, but also have it bubble up properties from the subquery.

For example, lets say I have an object called car and I have an object called dealership. Now I want to pull the dealership that a particular car is located at based on some query parameters. This is where the compound query comes in.

I know how to create the compound query to only return cars that belong to a particular dealership, but how would I return the "name" property from the dealership object on my car object?

The idea here is to mimic a left join in SQL to return data from a joined table.

Any ideas how one would do this?

Comment: What is the relationship between Car and Dealership?

Comment: It doesn't really matter does it? It's just an example I used to explain the type of question I'm asking. You can make one up if you'd like such as a dealershipID or something. Really, all I want to know is how do I make a compound query that can combine the data from two tables. such as you would get from a left join in SQL.